# getChildNodes() on org.w3c.dom.Node returns NodeLits of only nulls

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to parse a configuration file, but when I call getChildNodes() on the node excludes, the returned **NodeList** contains 7 null values and nothing else.

*My code*:

```
public class MinNull {

private static final List<String> excludes = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    File cfgFile = new File("ver.cfg");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(cfgFile);
    Element rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList cfg = rootElement.getChildNodes();
    parseConfig(cfg);
}

private static void parseConfig(NodeList cfg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cfg.getLength(); i++) {
        Node node = cfg.item(i);
        String name = node.getNodeName();
        switch (name) {
            case "excludes":
                NodeList exc = node.getChildNodes();
                for(int j = 0; j < exc.getLength();j++){
                    Node ex = exc.item(i);
                    System.out.println(ex);
                    if(ex != null && ex.getNodeName().equals("file")){
                        excludes.add(ex.getTextContent());
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

My **xml** file (named ver.cfg) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>
    <server>localhost</server>
    <port>6645</port>
    <project>MyApp</project>
    <mainfile>MyApp.jar</mainfile>
    <version>v1</version>
    <excludes>
        <file>Launcher.jar</file>
        <file>Launch.bat</file>
        <file>ver.cfg</file>
    </excludes>
</root>
```

Output:

```
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

Everything else is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the wrong index variable in

```
Node ex = exc.item(i);
```

you should have used `j` here.

At that point `i = 5`, and child node 5 does not exists, so you are getting the `null` indicating that that node does not exists.